# Synchronization in Firefox OS (B2G)

Tags: firefox-os

I would like to stop a function in order to wait the end of another section of code.
Is there in Firefox OS some synchronization method like wait() and notify() in Java?
Thanks

Comment: please provide your code. It sounds like you are trying to do something in JavaScript in a very unconventional way. If you post you code and explain what you are trying to achieve, you are much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't has this concept, but generally speaking uses callbacks (function pointers). A bit like the anonymous classes in Java. For example, I'm making a call to a web server:

```
function callToWebServer(url, doneCallback) {
   // do all kinds of magic, waiting for the web server to reply etc.
   // when done:
   doneCallback();
}
```

Now using it via:

```
callToWebServer(function() {
    // this is executed after the call to the web server succeeded
});
alert(1); // this is executed straight away
```

We can never wait, as JS is a single-thread execution environment. All code is written async.